# Gmap and many markers with popup

Tags: google-maps

**Situation**

We use gmap module to generate gmap and display markers on it.
When user click on marker we display popup, it works well if website display 100-200 markers only, however when it gets to 1000++ Drupal can't display such page.

**Issue**

Issue happens because Drupal exports all required information to display popup directly on page and it takes to much time generate that.

**What I've done so far**

I googled and did not find anything that could help me.
I know that google map API may deal with feed/xml (that's a direction I'm moving to), however I do not wanna create new wheel if it is already exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't have time for an answer (and I don't really recall how I have solved it before), but the solution you need is called "marker clustering", which is supported by the Google Maps V3 API.

Comment: @MPD I've cluster, but the issue is about popup data.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled? I'm assuming you're using views to generate the markers, try enabling views caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move information for popup from the page we have to use options: RMT callback path in a view.

It allows to make AJAX request to load content and so you do not need to put it on page with map. It's big performance improvement.

[image]